# Чи можна вважати певні фразеологізми архаїзмами та історизмами?

Tags: фразеологізми, архаїзми

Проводячи невелике дослідження, я з'ясувала, що більшість фразеологізмів, на данний момент, можна зустріти лише в книгах написаних у ХХ столітті.

Наприклад:

> Та Свирид Костомаха не того тіста книш. Мій батько… не брехав і синові не велів (Марко Вовчок, 6, 1956, с. 260);
>   Оскільки всі вони мали високі академічні звання, то й цей, звісно, був пташкою їхнього польоту (Гуцало, Парад планет, 1984, с. 99)
>   — Ну, та я теж не ликом шитий... Скажу, що була звичайна товариська зустріч (Бурлака, Напередодні, 1956, стор. 332);
>   — Чого ж мені? Я не від того, щоб учитись. Я з охотою... Але перше треба знати, чому вчи­тись і що то за вчитель буде. Ми теж не ликом шиті і не макогоном одуковані, хоч і не кінчали інститутів... (Добровольський, Тече річка невеличкaа, 1961, стор. 113).

Ще вони зустрічаються у посібниках для вивчення мови.

У широкому вжитку їх не використовують, а заміняють більш звичними в побуті словами.

Чи можна на таких засадах вважати всі фразеологізми - архаїзмами?

Comment: ви маєте на увазі "всі (ЦІ) фразеологізми" чи справді питаєте про "ВСІ фразеологізми"?

Answer (score 5):

Фразеологізм, хоч і має неподільне значення і не може сприйматися як сума значень слів у його складі, однак все ж граматично організований за моделлю словосполучення чи речення.

Фразеологізми вивчає розділ мовознавства - фразеологія. Тому використовувати щодо фразеологізмів класифікацію лексики (архаїзм, історизм) неправильно.

Утім, щодо вжитку фразеологізмів фахівці мають певні міркування:

> Переважна більшість фразеологізмів походить з усної народної
>   творчості...Фразеологізмами стали вислови античних часів... також
>   вислови з церковної літератури.

[ОСНОВНІ ТИПОЛОГІЧНІ ОЗНАКИ ФРАЗЕОЛОГІЗМІВ](http://pidruchniki.com/1209081040542/dokumentoznavstvo/frazeologiya)

> Застарілі фразеологізми відбивають і звичайні поняття, і такі, що з
>   різних причин вийшли з активного вжитку.

[Активні і пасивні фразеологізми](http://schoollib.com.ua/ukr_lang/1/43.html)

Пасивні одиниці мови мало або зовсім не вживаються у повсякденному спілкуванні через те, що містять позначення предметів і явищ, застарілих для сучасного мовця.

*піти під аршин, забігти в колодку, прописати іжицю*

Можемо використовувати означення "застарілий" до фразеологізмів, що мають у складі слова-архаїзми і через те стають незрозумілі і непопулярні.

Щодо питання, чи не відмирає взагалі фраземіка мови, то відповідь - категорично ні. Ми не кажемо більше "не ликом шитий", але маємо безліч нових фразем ХХІ століття, створених за законами фраземіки із сучасних лексичних одиниць для обслуговування сучасних понять, як-от "шокова терапія", "тіньова економіка", "стакан наполовину повний" тощо.